# To find the range of $\sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{5-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To find the range of $\sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{5-x}$.

I do not know how to start?

Thanks

Comment: In this way i get $[0,\infty]$

Comment: Hem, try with $x=6$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $1\le x\le5$

If $y=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{5-x}>0, y^2=4+2\sqrt{(x-1)(5-x)}$

Now $\sqrt{(x-1)(5-x)}\ge0$

and using AM-GM inequality, $\sqrt{(x-1)(5-x)}\le\dfrac{x-1+5-x}2=?$

Comment: so the answer is $y\in[2, 2\sqrt 2]$?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Where do you find $3$?

Comment: My bad, $2$. Discarding my comments.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, What if $x=5$ or $1$? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\left(\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{5-x}\right)^2=4+2\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}
$$
Since $4-(x-3)^2\le4$ and $4+2\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}\ge4$, we get that
$$
2\le\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{5-x}\le2\sqrt2
$$

Comment: Is it true that is range of $f^2= [a,b]$ then range of $f =[\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}]$

Comment: When it is guaranteed that $f\ge0$, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{5-x}$ for $x\in[1,5]$.

i) Show that $f(x)=f(6-x)$ ($f$ is symmetric with respect to $x=3$).

ii) $f$ is strictly increasing in $(1,3)$, that is
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5-x}}>0$$

iii) $f([1,5])=[f(1),f(3)]$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{5-x}\ge0$$ then

$$y^2=4+2\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{5-x}\ge4$$ and

$$(y^2-4)^2=4(x-1)(5-x)\ge0.$$

The positive range of the RHS is $[0,16]$. Then the range of $y^2-4$ is $[0,4]$ and that of $y$ is $[2,\sqrt8]$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $1\le x\le5$

As $\dfrac{1+5}2=3, 1-3\le x-3\le5-3$

WLOG $x-3=2\cos2y,$  where $0\le2y\le\pi$

$\sqrt{x-1}=2\cos y$  and $\sqrt{5-x}=2\sin y$

Now $\sin y+\cos y=\sqrt2\sin\left(y+\dfrac\pi4\right)$ and $0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\le\sin\left(y+\dfrac\pi4\right)\le1$

Comment: Any other method please